# I don't understand the definition of $L^p(\partial\Lambda)$, for some bounded and open $\Lambda\subseteq\mathbb R^d$

Tags: lp-spaces

Let $d\in\mathbb N$, $\Lambda\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be bounded and open and $p\ge 1$. In the definition of the [trace operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_operator#Construction_of_the_trace_operator), we consider the space $L^p(\partial\Lambda)$? But since $\partial\Lambda$ has Lebesgue measure zero and $L^p(\partial\Lambda)$ is a set of equivalence classes of Lebesgue almost equal functions, shouldn't it contain only the equivalence class of the zero function $\partial\Lambda\to\mathbb R$?

Comment: When you say $\partial \Lambda$ has Lebesgue measure zero, you mean $\lambda_{\mathbb{R}^d}(\partial \Lambda) = 0$. Which is correct, but here $L^p(\partial\Lambda)$ is equipped with the Lebesgue measure on $\partial \Lambda$ and of course $\lambda_{\partial \Lambda}(\partial \Lambda) = 1$.

Comment: @anonymus If $\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d)$ denotes the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and $λ$ the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^d$, then the Lebesgue measure on $∂\Lambda$ is the trace $\left.λ\right|_{∂\Lambda}$ of $λ$ on $∂\Lambda$, $$\left.λ\right|_{∂\Lambda}:=\left.λ\right|_{\left.\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d)\right|_{∂\Lambda}}$$ where $$\left.\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d)\right|_{∂\Lambda}:=\left\{A\cap ∂\Lambda:A\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d)\right\}=\mathcal B(∂\Lambda)$$ (note that $∂\Lambda\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d)$). So, $$\left.λ\right|_{∂\Lambda}(∂\Lambda)=λ(∂\Lambda)=0\;.$$ What am I missing?